# EmberJS: How to retrieve associated records when using the Fixture adapter

Tags: ember.js

I have two models:

```
BuzsakiViewer.Neuron = DS.Model.extend
  number: DS.attr()
  plots: DS.hasMany 'plot', { async: true }

BuzsakiViewer.Plot = DS.Model.extend
  filename: DS.attr()
  neuron: DS.belongsTo('neuron')
  path: ( ->
    'images' + '/' + @get('filename') 
  ).property('filename')
```

Below is a sample `neuron` fixture and a sample `plot` fixture. My actual declarations have more records:

```
BuzsakiViewer.Neuron.FIXTURES = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "plots": [ 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87 ]
  }
]

BuzsakiViewer.Plot.FIXTURES = [
  {
    "filename": "n1_avgleft.png",
    "id": 80,
    "neuron": 1
  }
]
```

I have a nested route **neuron/:neuron_id/plots**, which should set the model to the plots for a particular neuron:

```
BuzsakiViewer.Router.map ->
  @resource 'neurons'
  @resource 'neuron', path: '/neurons/:neuron_id', ->
    @route 'plots'
  @resource 'plots'
  @resource 'plot', path: '/plots/:plot_id'

BuzsakiViewer.NeuronPlotsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('neuron', params.neuron_id).then (neuron) ->
      neuron.get('plots')
```

But when I go to **/neurons/:neuron_id/plots**, no plots are loaded. There is no error, but I can see in the Chrome Ember Inspector that no model is bound for the NeuronPlots route. I am sure that all the plots in the `plots` field of the neuron record I'm loading are present in the `Plot.FIXTURES` declaration. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nueron Plots route won't get the neuron_id, so you are probably querying for undefined.  You can use modelFor to get the resource of the route above and then call get plots on it, so it will look something like this (pardon my lack of coffeescript skills)

```
BuzsakiViewer.NeuronPlotsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @modelFor('nueron').get('plots')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Seems strange that URL params aren't available to child routes.

Comment: That has been a matter of contention amongst a plethora of people.  It partially has to do with the fact that the route can define different url params and they wanted to avoid clashing params.  There are ways to solve it, but it hasn't been done as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a controller using needs - [Dependencies between controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)